# Ant Design Pro: how to redirect route keeping query parameters

Tags: reactjs, ant-design-pro

My user will receive a link with a key that is unique to them that will direct them to a step form. When they come into the step form I want to redirect them to the first step automatically inside the router.config.
i.e. they will receive a url that looks like:

```
https://example.com/register/user/sales?key=1234
```

and they must be redirected to:

```
https://example.com/register/user/sales/account?key=1234
```

However once my user is redirected the query parameter "?key=1234" is lost.
How do I fix this?

I've set up router.config as follows:

```
export default [{
    path: '/register',
    component: '../layouts/RegisterLayout',
    routes: [{
        path: '/register',
        redirect: '/register/user'
    }, {
        path: '/register/user',
        name: 'user',
        component: './Register/user'
    }, {
        path: '/register/user/:division',
        name: 'user',
        component: './Register/User',
        hideChildrenInMenu: true,
        routes: [{
            path: '/register/user/:division',
            redirect: '/register/user/:division/account'
        }, {
            path: '/register/user/:division/account',
            name: 'account',
            component: './Register/User/Step1CreateAccount'
        }, {
            path: '/register/user/:division/details',
            name: 'details',
            component: './Register/User/Step2UserDetails'
        }]
  }]
}]
```

Comment: Extract the parameters from `this.props.location` and attach it to next route before redirection

Answer (score 2):

The query preservation cant be done in this file, rather in file that renders Links. I belive ant-design-pro is using UMI by default, so you are looking at something like:

```js
import Link from 'umi/link';

export default () => {
  <div>
    /* Normal use */
    <Link to="/list">Go to list page</Link>
    
    /* With query string */
    <Link to="/list?a=b">Go to list page</Link>

    /* Include child component */
    <Link to="/list?a=b"><button>Go to list page</button></Link>
  </div>
}
```

something similiar to this should be done in SiderMenu or anywhere else, where you have links.